How to check if the text of an entry is changed by keyboard input or by c# (or VB) in .NET MAUI
I am creating a simple calculator in MAUI as this is my first time using MAUI.
So, I have an Entry to display the entered numbers, operations and the answer. There are two ways to change the text in the Entry: The keyboard and the buttons (C#) given in the UI. I want to detect if the text in the Entry is changed by keyboard input or by using the UI buttons (C#).
I am using .NET 8 targeting Windows and Android.
I tried using the TextChanged event but it runs every time the text changes (it doesn't differentiate between Keyboard input and C#). Then I tried to use the KeyPress event, but I don't know where and how to use it, or does it even work in MAUI.
Why do I need to check? - I want that only numbers, decimal point and the mathematical operations should be in the Entry.
So, if the input is coming from the UI buttons, don't check anything and just append the text. And if the input is coming from the keyboard then check the input and then decide weather to append or not.

AFAIK, that's not possible with MAUI (by default). Why do you need this? Please elaborate on the problem that this solves, maybe there is another solution. Which platform(s) are you targeting?

unless your validation routine is very expensive, it shouldn't hurt to validate both button and keyboard input.

Actually there is no proper validation route. If a UI button is pressed, it directly appends to the Entry.

If the input is done by keyboard, then only there is need to check.

Isn't it much more efficient to just use the TextChanged event and validate the entry anyway? In a calculator app, the cost of validating the input regardless of how it was made should be negligible, especially if it runs on Windows which implies a full blown computer with decent amount of memory. Even on an Android device, that validation shouldn't cost much especially if you use RegEx for validation.

Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't think about that when I posted this question. My original issue is solved. But anyways, is there any way this can be done? It might be useful in any other situation.

Use several buttons and data-binding to implement it. And show the result or the calculated steps by Label. Here is a simple https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/fundamentals/mvvm?view=net-maui-8.0#commanding

Hi @NinadKulkarni, My original issue is solved.  Could you please shared the solution you used so that it will help others who have similar problems? :)

@Jessie Zhang -MSFT, I used the solution used by Sam. Check the 5th comment from the top.

Hi @NinadKulkarni, thanks for your feedback.  As a summary, I will post an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems. :)

I'm not sure how efficient this might be, but what if you use a binding for it?
Create two variables:
private string _calculatorText { get; set; }
public string CalculatorText
{
    get => _calculatorText;
    set
    {
        _calculatorText = value;
        bool usingKeyboard = true;
        SomeMethod(usingKeyboard);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CalculatorText));
    }
}

And in your XAML entry, bind the text like this:
xml
<Entry Text="{Binding CalculatorText}" />

This way, when you detect the change through CalculatorText, you know it was done via the keyboard. In contrast, if you handle _calculatorText directly, it was done through C# code.

Yes, we can use event TextChanged to validate the input just as Sam said.
InputView has defines a TextChanged event, which is raised when the text in the Entry changes. The TextChangedEventArgs object that accompanies the TextChanged event has NewTextValue and OldTextValue properties, which specify the new and old text, respectively.
void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string oldText = e.OldTextValue;
    string newText = e.NewTextValue;
    string myText = entry.Text;
}

For more information, you can check document: Entry.
